# Auto-perform actions when updating a mutable in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, getter-setter

I know how to use property setters to perform actions every time an attribute of a class is modified to avoid having to code in every action every time the variable is changed.

I wanted to know if it was possible to do the same for mutables, like lists and dictionaries ?

What I want to achieve is the following,

I have a dictionary `d = {string : object}`

with `object` an instance of a class which has an attribute called `x`.

when I add a new `string:object` pair to my dictionary, and that the attribute `x` of the object is `!= 0`, then I also add the `object` to a list called `x_instances`.

Comment: Well - you could do that - are you not in a position that before you update the `dict` to do a simple `if` first?

Comment: I could the thing is that my actual case is a bit more complex, but also very repetitive, so to avoid having to worry about coding in the same thing everywhere that I edit the dictionary I was thinking this could make things a bit easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to use a custom class; you could subclass `dict` or  [`collections.UserDict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#userdict-objects), and override the appropriate [container special methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types) to detect changes.

For example, `object[subscription] = value` is translated to `object.__setitem__(subscription, value)`, letting you inspect `value` and act on that:

```
class MutationDictionary(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        super().__setitem__(key, value)
        if isinstance(value, SomeClass) and value.x != 0:
            x_instances.append(value)
```

Do look over the [other methods that `dict` objects implement](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict); you may want to override `dict.setdefault()` too for example.